# Populate userform error "type mismatch"

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm currently having a problem with populating a user form.

**Problem**: when I put in a ticket # and press search, i want the userform to populate. But when I try to run it, a type mismatch occurs. I've tried setting the text box's as integer or string and change the source in the worksheet to the respected type but then a invalid qualifier occurs.

whats funny is I tried to simplify it, to test the code and it works so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cbSearch_Click()

Dim vResult

'not sure if these are needed or not
'Dim TextBox2 As Integer
'Dim TextBox9 As Integer
'Dim TextBox4 As String

vResult = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("Journal").Range("A2:A10000"), Me.TextBox1.Value)

If vResult > 0 Then
    'Error occurs here. "Could not set the Value properly. type mismatch. But when I try to set it(TextBox2, TextBox9, etc..)
    'as a string or Integer it comes back as invalid qualifier
    TextBox2.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 14, False)
    TextBox9.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 15, False)
    TextBox4.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 5, False)

    'I also want the data to be imported to the userform to check the checkbox if it applies. I used 1 for true and 0 for false
    CheckBox1.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 30, False)
    CheckBox2.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 31, False)
Else
    MsgBox "No match found. Please try again."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Check the results of your VLookups - Are the first three returning strings (or something that can be implicitly cast to a string)?  Are the last two returning booleans?

Answer (score 0):

Try to "clean" your VLookup results using CStr and change the TextBoxes property to ".Text".

```
Me.TextBox2.Text= Cstr(Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 14, False))
```

The checkboxes what you can do is an IF statement

```
If Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 30, False) = 0 then
CheckBox1.Value = False
Else
CheckBox1.Value = True
End if
```

Also you don't need to declare the "TextBox" variable, it's an object you just reference it directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter way to set the Checkbox.

```
CheckBox1.Value = Cbool(If Application.VLookup(TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 30, False))
```

This formula will return True if the VLookup returns any number and False, if it returns 0. Use `On Error Resume Next` to accommodate the possibility that VLookup returns an error. For example,

```
Dim Chk As Boolean
Chk = False
On Error Resume Next
Chk =  Cbool(If Application.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Journal").Range("A:BA"), 30, False))
On Error Goto 0        ' reinstates "Break on error"
CheckBox1.Value - Chk
```

If the VLookup returns an error, `Chk` will retain the value assigned to it before the call, in the above code `False`.

Note that the Value of a Checkbox is a Boolean (True/False). VB will convert a 0 that you assign to False and might convert a 1 to True. Actually, the numeric equivalent of True is -1 but VB will coerce some values when it feels it understands the user's intention.